# Entering previous data with textinput using Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I face a issue when designing a login page. And this issue is only for Firefox.

That is, when I selecting a previous login id and pressing Enter then caused the submit.

in IE and Chrome, it only select the data and doesn't submit.

my code is like :

```
<input type="text" name="t1"><br>
<input type="text" name="t2"><br>

<script>
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
if (e.which == 13)
// submit
}
</script>
```

for example :

http://ppt.cc/c048

when I select "123" and press Enter, then my input submit. (for Firefox)

I expect that it only put the id "123" in the text box without doing submit action...

How can it still have the enter submit function without the Firefox issue?

Thank you!!

Comment: Only have the form submit if the password field is in focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I understand your question correctly, but if you can't get the Enter key submit the form in Firefox, try this for your script bit

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 || e.charCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        // submit
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a problem i was having a while back i fexed it like so

```
<script>
  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // submit
    }
  }
</script>
```